# CFWheels & Oracle 11g: Pagination on Group by data with

Tags: oracle11g, coldfusion, cfwheels

I am using Oracle 11g database with my CFWheels project. As known Oracle 11g doesn't support LIMIT and OFFSET.

```
//un-grouped data
data1 = model("tb_test_1").findAll(order="id");
//grouped data
data2 = model("tb_test_1").findAll(select="MAX(tb_test_1.category) as category, COUNT(tb_test_1.category) as count", group="category");
//grouped data with pagination
data3 = model("tb_test_1").findAll(select="MAX(tb_test_1.category) as category, COUNT(tb_test_1.category) as count", page=1, perPage=2, group="category");
```

Above is my database call from my action/controller and below are the outputs

[image]

Now if you look at the last result and its query, that is where I am attempting to paginate the grouped data. However it seems to be using WHERE clause to do some sort of filtering, which exclude the records I want to be included in the group. I apologize if I can't explain better but I just want the data in result # 2 (middle query) to be paginated. How do I do that in CFWheels using Oracle 11g database